# How does argument passing work in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I know that in Java, if I pass an object to a method as an argument, then the method will let the argument variable point to the same object rather than making a duplicate. How about in Clojure? For example:

```
(defn print-from-reader [rdr]
   (print (.read rdr)))

(...inside some code...
  (with-open [rdr (Reader file)]
    (print-from-rader rdr)))
```

Does print-from-reader make another copy of rdr in memory when rdr is passed in, or it's pointing to the same rdr that's already created by with-open binding?

And is there any way to check if two clojure instances are pointing to same memory?

Sorry about my bad terms such as "pointing to" and "instances", I am a newbie in Clojure and still learning it. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure is pass-by-value just like Java. I think of it as, the references are passed by value. 
It isn't a stretch for Clojure to work like this, Scheme and Common Lisp behave the same way.

You can test whether two references point to the same memory with [`identical?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/identical_q):

> (identical? x y)
>
> Tests if 2 arguments are the same object

Comment: (identical?) looks pretty handy, now I learned another trick! :-)

Answer (score 7):

According to answer to [this question on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/5LosIrRXnOY) it's pass by value.

> Clojure inherits the argument-passing semantics from Java. So it is pass-by-value, where the value passed is an object reference. In addition there are optimization facilities that enable the passing of primitive-typed values.

So functions don't make copies when parameters are passed. `rdr` in your code will be the same instance.

Makes sense to implement it like that due to java interoperability - otherwise you couldn't (easily) modify java objects' state with its method.

You can test it easily:

```
(import 'java.util.HashMap)
(def m (new HashMap))
(defn foo [m] (defn bar [m] (.put m "testkey" "testvalue")) (bar m) (println (get m "testkey")))

(foo m)
```

Results in :

```
testvalue
nil
```

If `bar` created its own copy of `m`, then the `println` wouldn't print the value assigned inside `bar`.